Variance of Conditional Distribution (conditioning on the sum)
Suppose you have two continuous independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, with variances $\sigma_X^2$ and $\sigma_Y^2$, respectively. I want to compute the variance (more accurately, I just want a lower bound) of the distribution $Y | X+Y = u.$ If it makes things easier, you can assume that $Y$ is Gaussian, but not $X$.
If $X$ and $Y$ are both Gaussian, then this is easy using Gaussian conditioning formulas. I'm a little lost on how to do this for the more general case, but I feel intuitively it shouldn't be too difficult to get a crude bound (I don't need a very precise lower bound, but I am having difficulty even getting a rudimentary lower bound). I tried using Bayes' rule to do some computation, but it got messy and didn't really seem like the right approach.
Any thoughts would be appreciated!
